# Laravel vendor:publish directory permission issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a package that needs to publish to these directories when `php artisan vendor:publish` is called.

**Directories includes**

```
public_path('vendor/package/assets')
resources_path('vendor/package/views')
resources_path('vendor/package/translations')
```

I get permission related error when I run `vendor:publsih` which tries to write to these directories.

However `vendor:publish` works for `database_path('migrations')`.

Laravel requires permission 775 for `storage` and `bootstrap/cache`.

I don't want package users to be forced to give write permission to public and resources directories.

NB:My package already uses $this->loadViewsFrom, $this->loadTranslationsFrom and $this->loadMigrationsFrom as default options. I wish to give my package users full access to modify views, translations, migrations etc. My package also needs to publish some assets to `public` directory such as js, css etc, which are very necessary for some views.

What am I missing about `artisan vendor:publish`, and how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

In your package's service provider `boot` method, you should rely on the `loadViewsFrom` and `loadTranslationsFrom` methods to properly include views and translations files:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/views', 'courier');
    $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/translations', 'courier');
}
```

More information about including views can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages#views) and translations [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages#translations).

If you are looking to publish the files instead of just loading them for use, then use the `publishes` method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/path/to/assets' => public_path('vendor/courier'),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. My package  already uses  $this->loadViewsFrom,  $this->loadTranslationsFrom and  $this->loadMigrationsFrom as default options. I wish to give my  package users full access to modify views, translations, migrations etc. My package also need to publish some assets to  'public' directory such js, css which are very necessary for some views

Comment: Are you using `$this->publishes`?